# __radd__ operation with numpy number results to __getitem__ loop

Tags: python, numpy

I am implementing a class that handles basic binary operations such as addition, multiplication, subraction and division with their respective variants (reversed, in-place). I encountered an unexpected behaviour that I am trying to understand. Unfortunately, even by looking at numpy's implementation of `__add__` of `unsignedinteger`, I can not.

To reproduce this behavior you can simply run this code :

```
import numpy as np


class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def __len__(self):
        return 1

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print("getitem")
        return self.a

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.a + other


a = test()
b = np.uint8(1) + a
```

It will result in a `__getitem__` loop.
Of course my actual code works a bit differently but still faces the exact same issue.
I also tried to use python debugger in order to better understand the behavior of the operation that actually was called.
What I wish to do is mainly, when I run this code :

```
b = np.uint8(10) + test()
```

To actually execute `__radd__` operation. I understand it is happening because `numpy.unsignedinteger.__add__` is execute. Is there any pythonic way to prevent or even better, to fix it ?

Comment: What do you need *len* for?

Comment: In my actual code, __len__ returns the first dimension of the data my class is handling. As numpy does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand it is happening because `numpy.unsignedinteger.__add__` is execute. Is there any pythonic way to prevent or even better, to fix it ?

Given the expression `np.uint8(10) + test()` there is no way your `test` class can prevent the calling of numpy's `__add__` method.

Only if numpy returned `NotImplemented` in their method your `__radd__` would be called.

The infinite `__getitem__` loop you are seeing is happening, because your class behaves like an infinite sequence and numpy wants to add their scalar to every element of that infinite sequence. That will never finish.

You have two ways to fix this. First option: make your class a proper finite sequence and let numpy handle the operation. This will not call your `__radd__` method.

To make your class a finite sequence you must `raise IndexError` in your `__getitem__` when the index is larger than zero or less than negative one (`-1`).

The second option: get rid of your `__getitem__` method. Then numpy realizes it cannot add itself to your type, return `NotImplemented` and let your `__radd__` method handle the operation.

Comment: "and numpy wants to add their scalar to every element of that infinite sequence. " oh wow. yeah I didn't even realize `numpy` scalar types behaved that way!

Comment: Indeed, I noticed in my implementation that __getitem__ was occurring for each element composing the current object. Unfortunately, this object is on GPU side, meaning that elementwise addition handled by numpy itself is really inefficient (in reality not possible). Thanks a lot for your explanation. I guess in the documentation I will highlight the fact that calling reversed binary operation is a source of troubles. Thanks again.